# R言語の==の不可解な挙動

Tags: r

```
> cos(pi/4)
[1] 0.7071068
> sin(pi/4)
[1] 0.7071068
> cos(pi/4)==sin(pi/4)
[1] FALSE
```

これは、無理数どうしで、しょうがないかなと思うのですが、

```
> cos(pi/3)
[1] 0.5
> sin(pi/6)
[1] 0.5
> cos(pi/3)==sin(pi/6)
[1] FALSE
```

というように、有理数どうしで同じ値でも、等しくないとみなされます。どのような説明が可能でしょうか。ちなみに、

```
> (sqrt(2))^2
[1] 2
> (sqrt(2))^2==2
[1] FALSE
```

というように、整数どうしで同じ値でも、等しくないとみなされる場合があります。ぜひとも、一般論を教えてください。

Comment: こちら [R-Source 数値計算・其の壱](http://cse.naro.affrc.go.jp/takezawa/r-tips/r/37.html) が参考になると思います。整数なら `round()` 、実数なら `signif()` で処理すれば `TRUE` になります。

Comment: そうすると、整数ならround()、実数ならsignif()を使わないと、==は期待どうりの答えを出さないのでしょうか。

Comment: 有効桁数の設定に依るかと思います。例えば、`signif(2.0) == signif(2.000001)` は TRUE になってしまいます(`signif()`のデフォルトの有効桁数が6桁なので)。

Comment: 精度が有限である以上piが円周率と等しくないので`cos(pi/3)==sin(pi/6)`が偽なのは当たり前ではないでしょうか。

Comment: 対処療法を考えることは難しくないと思います。今回の質問は、なぜそのような挙動をするのか、ということを知りたいということです。

Comment: 1/3も有限精度のものとは違っています。それにもかかわらず、1/3*3==1は真になります。私の経験では、有理数では、無限小数であっても、そのような不具合が生じていません。なので、「当たり前」という結論にはならないと思います。

Answer (score 3):

Rの公式のFAQに書かれている説明です。

[7.31 Why doesn't R think these numbers are equal?](http://www.hep.by/gnu/r-patched/r-faq/R-FAQ_82.html)

> The only numbers that can be represented exactly in R's numeric type
>   are integers and fractions whose denominator is a power of 2. Other
>   numbers have to be rounded to (typically) 53 binary digits accuracy.
>   As a result, two floating point numbers will not reliably be equal
>   unless they have been computed by the same algorithm, and not always
>   even then.

Rにおける数値型で正確に表現できる数値は、整数及び分母が2の冪である分数のみです。その他の数値は（一般的には）53桁の２進数の精度に丸められます。
結果的に、同じアルゴリズムによって計算されない限り２つの浮動小数点数が確実に等しくなることはなく、場合によってはそれすら保証されません。

Comment: 浮動小数点どうしの比較には、使えないという結論でしょうか。普通の整数でも、typeof()という関数をもちいると、double(浮動小数)であると表示されます。特別に、as.integer()とやらないとそうなります。そうなると、1/2*2==1などは、両辺ともtypeof()がdoubleなので、正しい値が出なくても良い(仕様を満足している)ということでしょか。

Comment: そのような、仕様が明確に記載されている、cranのページやURLなど、ございますでしょうか。

Comment: 公式のページに書かれていることは、わかりました。そこには、間違いは含まれていないと思いますが、私が聞きたい情報は含まれていないと思います。私の経験では、有理数同士の四則演算では、ひとつもこのような問題は生じていません。上記の引用によって、それは、どのように説明がつきますでしょうか。それとも、有理数同士の四則演算でも、そのような問題が生じる例が存在するのでしょうか。

Comment: 例えば1e20 + 1 == 1e20もTRUEとなります。（一見整数ですが内部では浮動小数です）尚、0.1は有理数ですが浮動小数としては正確に表せないことが知られています。ですので、有理数かどうかはここでは関係がないように思います。

Comment: 1/3*3==1 が真となるように、有理数どうしの四則演算で、FALSEになるような例が見いだせないと思うのですが、判例はありますか。

Comment: @JoeSuzuki 1 / (15 ** 80) * (15 ** 80) == 1 はFALSEになります。

Comment: それは、わかりました。そうなると、私の質問の答えは、どうなりますか、as.integerとやらない限り、numericのオブジェクトはdouble(浮動小数)です。typeof(1)とやると、integerではなく、doubleと出力されます。つまり、==はほとんどのケースで、正しい答えを出す保証がない、と結論づけられますか。

Comment: つきつめていえば、==でただし答えがでてくるための、必要十分条件は、しられていない、というのが、回答になりますか。

Comment: この問題は浮動小数点数で小数を表現していることに起因しています。Rに限らず、[IEEE 754 - Wikipedia](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) に準じた実装を採用している場合は、**そのままで等値比較はしない**というのがお約束になります。(言語によっては固定小数点数が用意されているものがあり、こちらは精度内の値であれば一致を保証できます）。

Comment: ==は、どんな言語でも、整数どうしとか、そういう場合以外は、保証されないし、そういう比較をしようとするのは、スジが悪い、と理解するのが一番よいようですね。つまり、成立するか否かの境界線を明確にするということは、あまり意味がないということですね。よくわかりました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 2):

`R`の数値は浮動小数点ですので、一般的なプログラミング言語での浮動小数点の比較と同じ注意が必要です。

```
> sin(pi/6) - 0.5
[1] -5.551115e-17
> cos(pi/3) - 0.5
[1] 1.110223e-16
```

のように、実際には異なる数値ですので、等値比較はFALSEになります。

よくある方法としてはあらかじめ許容誤差を決めておき、それを含めて判定するということをやります。

```
> epsilon <- 1e-10
> abs(sin(pi/6) - cos(pi/3)) <= epsilon
[1] TRUE
```

以下の質問投稿で、こうした誤差を考慮した比較用関数を自前で用意するという案もでていました。

cf. [floating point - Numeric comparison difficulty in R - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769510/numeric-comparison-difficulty-in-r)

Comment: 実際に値が異なるのは、そのとおりだと思います。どのような条件だと同じでどのようなときに違うのかの必要十分条件のようなことがわかれば、と思いました。
たとえば、 (sqrt(2))^2==2でFALSE、1/3*3==1はTRUEとでます。それぞれがなぜか、例外なく、説明できるようにしたいと思っていました。いかがでしょうか。

Comment: h2so5さんの書かれているように、言語仕様としては浮動小数点などでの別個の計算結果が同じになることは保証されていません。`a<-1/3`として`a*3==1`もTRUEとなりますが、偶然一致するのでしょう。肝としては浮動小数点の等値比較は誤差を考慮するか入力データの有効桁で丸めるなどして、そのままでは比較しないという事だと考えています。

Comment: 浮動小数点というのは、typeofがdoubleになるオブジェクトのことでしょうか。もし、そうだとすれば、Rでは、as.integerとやらない限り、整数でもdoubleになるので、==の適用範囲が非常にせまくなります。